# PDF input format for Mapreduce Hadoop

Tags: maven, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I anm using PDFBOX external library for parsing the pdf input file in mapreduce,but i am getting the following error.

> Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
>           at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
>           at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
>           at com.nielsen.grfe.processor.mapreduce.Pdfparser$PdfLineRecordReader.initialize(Pdfparser.java:109)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:548)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:786)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:341)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1671)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)

I am using the following dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdfbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.pdfbox</groupId>
        <artifactId>fontbox</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: @prashant khunt I have added Distributed cache  in the code..Still i face the same error..

Answer (score 0):

1) Place the jar file of pdfbox in hadoop lib folder too.(make library jar    available to hadoop at runtime).

2) Restart hadoop cluster.

Or

1) Make sure that your pdfbox library is available to hadoop by placing it in distributed cache.

Comment: org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument is not available in the PDFBOX 1.8.10.

Comment: As per java docs, https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.10/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html  the class is present in PDFBOX 1.8.10. The class is also present in the jar file. can you please paste the Exception that you are getting?